# Странное поведение Imagick::cropImage()

Tags: php, imagemagick

Вот код:

```
$bg = new Imagick('./resourses/back.png');

$b = $bg;
$b->cropImage(100, 50, 0, 40);
$b->writeImage('cropped.png');
$b = $bg;
$b->writeImage('test.png');
```

В файл `cropped.png` записывается обрезанная картинка, как и должно быть. В файл `test.png` должна записаться нетронутая картинка `back.png`, которая содержится в переменной `$bg`. Но в файл `test.png` записывается обрезанная картинка - ровно та же, что и в `cropped.png`. Почему это происходит?

Comment: Дело в том, что объекты присваиваются по ссылке. Т.е. вот тут `$b = $bg;` переменной `$b` присваивается ссылка на объект `$bg` и когда вы ее обрезают, то, по факту, обрезается `$bg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Оператор присваивания](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.assignment.php)

> Исключением из обычного для PHP способа присваивания по значению
>   явлаются объекты (object), которые, начиная с версии PHP 5,
>   присваиваются по ссылке. Принудительно скопировать объекты по значению
>   можно с помощью специального ключевого слова clone.

Т.е. вот тут `$b = $bg;` переменной `$b` присваивается ссылка на объект `$bg` и когда вы ее кропаете, то, по факту, кропается изображение в объекте `$bg`.

Вам нужно либо использовать [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php), либо создавать два объекта.